# Finding the 5 youngest users who have valid US telephone numbers - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++17

Continuing from: [Part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231760/finding-the-5-youngest-users-who-have-valid-us-telephone-numbers?noredirect=1#comment452209_231760)

I was not convinced this was true (see comment):

```
std::async([&users, job = std::make_unique<ListJob>(apiList)](){job->run(users);});
// This will not return until all async jobs have completed.
```

So I rewrote it to make sure that I waited for all child work. This means collecting and then waiting on all `future<void>` objects.

Additionally I did not want parallelism to grow out of control. So I add a limit `maxParrallelism` for the maximum number of details that could be retrieved in parallel (this is simply limited by the number of open connection an application is allowed by but I thought a practical limit would be 20 until I can test and prove otherwise).

The interesting parallel work has been pulled into the class `JobHolder` (I have broken that out separately for review (but currently it is all one big file)).

JobHolder:

```
class JobHolder
{
    std::vector<User>&                          users;
    std::map<int, std::future<void>>            userFutures;
    std::mutex                                  mutex;
    std::condition_variable                     cond;
    int                                         lastFinished;
    bool                                        justWaiting;
    public:
        JobHolder(std::vector<User>& users)
            : users(users)
            , lastFinished(-1)
            , justWaiting(false)
        {}
        void addJob(int userId)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex>     lock(mutex);

            // No more jobs if we are waiting.
            if (justWaiting) {
                return;
            }

            // We don't want to add more then maxParrallelism
            // simply because we don't want userFutures to blow up in memory to infinite size.
            // Note: Behind the scenes the parallelism is controlled for us by the implementation.
            cond.wait(lock, [&userFutures = this->userFutures](){return userFutures.size() < maxParrallelism;});

            // Start async job to create and handle connection.
            userFutures.emplace(userId, std::async([job = std::make_unique<UserJob>(apiDetail + std::to_string(userId), *this)](){job->run();}));
        }

        void addResult(User const& user)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex>   lock(mutex);

            if (std::regex_search(user.number, phoneNumber)) {
                // Add the user to a heap.
                // The heap is ordered by youngest person.
                users.emplace_back(std::move(user));
                std::push_heap(users.begin(), users.end(), youngestUser);
                if (users.size() == 6) {
                    // If we have more than 5 people the pop the oldest one off.
                    // Thus we maintain a heap of the 5 youngest people.
                    std::pop_heap(users.begin(), users.end(), youngestUser);
                    users.pop_back();
                }
            }

            // If we are waiting then a thread is in waitForAllJobs
            // So we can't remove items from the userFutures as it is being used.
            if (!justWaiting) {
                if (lastFinished != -1) {
                    // Note: Can't remove the current one (user.id)
                    //       As we are still in the thread that the future belongs too.
                    //       So we remove the last lastFinished and note this lastFinished
                    //       so it will be removed next time.
                    userFutures.erase(lastFinished);
                    cond.notify_one();
                }
                lastFinished = user.id;
            }
        }
        void waitForAllJobs()
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>     lock(mutex);
                justWaiting = true;
            }

            for(auto& future: userFutures) {
                future.second.wait();
            }
        }
};
```

The rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
#include <mutex>

#include "ThorSerialize/Traits.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/SerUtil.h"
#include "ThorSerialize/JsonThor.h"
#include "ThorsStream/ThorsStream.h"

using namespace std::string_literals;

// Some global constants.
const std::string api       = "https://appsheettest1.azurewebsites.net/sample"s;
const std::string apiList   = api + "/list"s;
const std::string apiDetail = api + "/detail/"s;
const std::regex  phoneNumber("^[0-9]{3}[- ][0-9]{3}[- ][0-9]{4}$");
const int         maxParrallelism = 20;

// In this app List and User
// are simply property bags no need to have access functions.
// If this was a more complex app then we would consider having other methods.
struct List
{
    std::vector<int>                result;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string>    token;
};

struct User
{
        int                     id;
        std::string             name;
        int                     age;
        std::string             number;
        std::string             photo;
        std::string             bio;

};

// Set up comparison functions used on user.
// Note: youngestUser uses both name and age. This is because if we have a lot of people at the same age we want to keep the
//       lexicographically lowest names as we eventually will sort by name.
const auto youngestUser = [](User const& lhs, User const& rhs){return std::forward_as_tuple(lhs.age, lhs.name) < std::forward_as_tuple(rhs.age, rhs.name);};
const auto nameTest     = [](User const& lhs, User const& rhs){return lhs.name < rhs.name;};

// Set up List and User to be read from JSON stream.
// See: jsonImport() and jsonExport() below
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(List, result, token);
ThorsAnvil_MakeTrait(User, id, name, age, number, photo, bio);


// A generic Job.
// Simply reads an object from an istream.
// If the read worked then processes it.
// Note: An istream treats a CURL socket like a standard C++ stream.
template<typename T>
class Job
{
    protected:
        ThorsAnvil::Stream::IThorStream     istream;
    public:
        Job(std::string const& url)
            : istream(url)
        {}
        virtual ~Job()
        {}

        void run()
        {
            bool hasMore;
            do
            {
                hasMore = false;
                T data;
                using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonImport;
                if (istream >> jsonImport(data)) {
                    processesData(data);
                    hasMore = moreData(data);
                }
                else {
                    // Do some error handling
                }
            }
            while(hasMore);
        }

        virtual void processesData(T const& data) = 0;
        virtual bool moreData(T const&) {return false;}
};

class JobHolder;

// A job to handle the details from getting a user object.
class UserJob: public Job<User>
{
    JobHolder&      jobHolder;
    public:
        UserJob(std::string const& url, JobHolder& jobHolder)
            : Job(url)
            , jobHolder(jobHolder)
        {}
        virtual void processesData(User const& user) override;
};

// ********
// JobHolder GOES HERE
// ********
// A job to handle the list object.
class ListJob: public Job<List>
{
    JobHolder   jobHolder;
    public:
        ListJob(std::string const& url, std::vector<User>& result)
            : Job(url)
            , jobHolder(result)
        {}
        virtual void processesData(List const& data) override;
        virtual bool moreData(List const& data) override;
};

void UserJob::processesData(User const& user)
{
    jobHolder.addResult(user);
}

void ListJob::processesData(List const& data)
{
    for(auto const& userId: data.result) {
        // For each user add a job ("UserJob") to the async queue.
        jobHolder.addJob(userId);
    }
}

bool ListJob::moreData(List const& data)
{
    if (data.token.get()) {
        istream = ThorsAnvil::Stream::IThorStream(apiList + "?token=" + *data.token);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        jobHolder.waitForAllJobs();
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<User>   users;

    ListJob listJob(apiList, users);
    listJob.run();

    std::sort(users.begin(), users.end(), nameTest);
    using ThorsAnvil::Serialize::jsonExport;
    std::cout << jsonExport(users) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is the assumption that it is going to take longer to process the data than to fetch it? It makes a difference as to how concurrency is best used.

Comment: @Edward: I did not think about that. I just tried to write it as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I see some things that may help you improve your program.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses a `condition_variable` but does not `#include <condition_variable>`.  It should!

### [Be careful with that mutex, Eugene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8OE4gedQuc)

It's not actually *wrong* but within `JobHolder::addResult`, the first line is this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex>   lock(mutex);
```

It's correct to grab the lock there, but you don't really need to unlock or relock after that, so it would be better to use the simpler `std::lock_guard` there instead.

### Minimize what's being protected by a mutex

The `JobHolder` class largely blocks parallel processing by its current design.  That's because the single `mutex` class member is locked before *any* data access which means that the code that processes the users queue is blocked while new user IDs are being fetched.  It seems to me that a finer grained locking mechanism would make more sense here.  Separate locks for the `users` and `userFuture` would simplify the locking regime, free up some otherwise blocked processing time and eliminate the need for the `justWaiting` and `lastFinished` items entirely.  Notionally, there are three tasks: fetching the user ids, fetching user details, and sorting them to process the query.  I would suggest that first two tasks can be asynchronous and only need to communicate via a shared `usersIds` vector.  The second two are also asynchronous and would only need to communicate via a `users` vector.  This suggests a rather different design in which a templated shareable vector (i.e. with suitable locking to assure coherency) could be the central coordinating data structures.  So instead of the current `JobHolder`, another possibility would be to augment the base `Job` class so that it has a shareable input and output queue.

### Use sentinels for all processing

Since there is apparently a sentinal data item that signals the end of the queue of user ids, that same idea could be used to signal the ids processor that there is no more data.  By having this signal within the data stream, it means there no longer needs to be an external signal for this notion, simplifying the code somewhat.

### Consider a map/reduce approach

Another way to approach this problem would be to have multiple threads each working on a subset of `User`s and each produce their own set of the five youngest.  Then those answers could be gathered and reduced to a single final set of five.

---

**Note:** The following items are from the earlier review of version 1, but are repeated here since they still apply.

---

### Use a better data structure

The use of the `heap` is not bad and is intuitively a reasonable structure for keeping the five youngest users, but because it's only five entries, I'd suggest that a `std::array<User,5>` might be better.  Even a linear search would require a very few comparisons and the advantage is that it's a fixed size structure.

### Do the cheaper tests first

Right now, the `processesData` function compares phone number first and then age.  Since the age comparison does not use a regex, I would strongly suspect that it is a less computationally expensive comparison, so it would probably make sense to do that first.  Obviously this is somewhat data-dependent, but it's worth thinking about.

### Use `regex_match` to match a whole string

The current code is using `regex_search` which looks for a match anywhere within the string, but the regex itself starts with `'^'` and ends with `'$'`, so clearly the intent is to only match the entire string.  For that, `regex_match` is more appropriate than `regex_search` and you can omit the start and end tokens from the regex.

### Minimize the time a mutex is held

Right now the code holds a mutex lock even before we know that this will actually alter the underlying structure.  That is, we may add a user who is older than the oldest person currently in the heap, only to remove that user again.  That's inefficient and holds the lock for longer than the mimimum time.  Instead, I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <mutex>

const std::regex  phoneNumber("[0-9][0-9][0-9][- ][0-9][0-9][0-9][- ][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");

struct User {
    std::string phone;
    int age{999};   // start with invalid age
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const User& user) {
    return out << "age: " << user.age << ", phone: " << user.phone;
}

const auto youngestUser = [](User const& lhs, User const& rhs){return lhs.age < rhs.age;};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    vector<User> samples{
        {"212-123-4567", 10},
        {"212-123-4568", 81},
        {"212-123-4569", 18},
        {"2 2-123-4570", 99},
        {"212-123-4571", 57},
        {"2 2-123-4572", 45},
        {"212-123-4573", 33},
        {"212-123-4574", 21},
        {"212-123-4575", 18},
        {"2 2-123-4576", 16},
        {"212-123-4577", 30},
        {"2 2-123-4578", 50},
        {"212-123-4579", 77},
        {"2 2-123-4580", 23},
    };

    array<User, 5> result;
    cout << "before:\n";
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), ostream_iterator<User>{cout, "\n"});
    for (const auto& person: samples) {
        if (person.age < result.back().age && regex_match(person.phone, phoneNumber)) {
            User youngerPerson(person);
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(mutex);
            if (person.age < result.back()) {
                swap(youngerPerson, result.back());
                sort(result.begin(), result.end(), youngestUser); 
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "after:\n";
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), ostream_iterator<User>{cout, "\n"});
}
```

Obviously this sample code is single-threaded, but it shows the suggested lock placement accurately.  It also shows doing one last comparison *after* the lock is obtained to avoid data race problems in which another thread has modified `result` between the time of the check and the time this thread obtains the lock.

**Caution:** accessing the data value of `person.back()` *without* locking the structure is inherently risky, but I believe it is OK in this particular case because:

1. all other threads will only add lower ages to the structure
2. because we're looking for human ages in years, this is extremely likely to be a single byte quantity and therefore atomic (even if it's stored in a `long int`)
3. the structure is a fixed-size `std::array` and so `person.back()` will not change address